# Why does ReplaceRepeated work differently in numerator and denominator?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, pattern-matching

I'm confused about the behavior of ReplaceRepeated.

`ReplaceRepeated[a Sqrt[b], Sqrt[b] -> c]` gives the expected `(* a c *)`, but

`ReplaceRepeated[1/(a Sqrt[b]), Sqrt[b] -> c]` yields `(* 1/(a Sqrt[b]) *)`.

Can someone explain that behavior, and how to correctly ask Mathematica to produce `(* 1/(a c) *)`?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Take a look at `1/(a Sqrt[b]) // FullForm`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand and will use ```FullFrom``` from now on before asking questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rohit mentioned, what you see on the screen is not necessarily what Mathematica sees. Using `FullForm` on your function shows that Mathematica actually sees

```
Times[Power[a, -1], Power[b, Rational[-1, 2]]]
```

whereas

```
Sqrt[b]//FullForm
```

gives

```
Power[b, Rational[1, 2]]
```

(note the difference in the first argument of `Rational`). You actually need something like

```
1/(a Sqrt[b])//. Power[b, _] -> 1/c
```

or

```
1/(a Sqrt[b]) //. Power[b, Rational[pow_, _]] :> c^Sign[pow]
```

In the second case, I'm asking it to match any pattern where we have `Power[b, Rational[..., ...]]`, then calling the first argument to `Rational` `pow` so that I can use it later, and then asking `c` to be raised to +1 if it's a positive number, and 1/c if it's a negative number. I don't know if you actually need something this complicated, but I thought I would include it to show how you can match more complicated patterns and extract pieces from those patterns.

Also, `//.` is shorthand for `ReplaceRepeated`. In these simple examples, you could get away with `ReplaceAll` which is just `/.`.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this so completely!

Comment: @StVir No problem, I'm glad it helped! I also found this counterintuitive when I was first learning. Also, welcome to MMA.SE. Make sure to accept whichever best answers your question, and don't forget to upvote questions and answers you find useful or interesting as your browse the site.