Replacement not working as desired
The following replacement works fine
ReplaceAll[1/F[x],F[x]->y]
(*1/y*)

but this doesn't
ReplaceAll[1/Sqrt[x],Sqrt[x]->y]
(*1/Sqrt[x]*)

The first one has F as its head while the second one has Power as its head, so I would expect it to work similarly?

The expression you are trying to replace is interpreted as Power[x, Rational[-1, 2]] whereas the Sqrt[x] pattern for replacement is Power[x, Rational[1, 2]], so they don't match.

See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/221369/1871 and Possible Issues section of document of FullForm: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html?q=FullForm https://i.sstatic.net/AoCUBT8J.png There should be more

see also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/29219#29219   The displayed form may substantially differ from the internal form
